# error Showing Data asp.net WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I try to get data from Database, I am using ado.net.
I am using a tutorial,and it works with another page contains relation between 2 classes.
But with this I am facing problem to get all data, and I already have data in database.
this is my code :

```
private void PopulateClients()
    {
        List<Client> allClients = null;
        using (MyDataBaseEntities dc = new MyDataBaseEntities())
        {
            var clients = (from a in dc.Clients
                                select new
                                {
                                    a
                                });
            if (clients != null)
            {
                allClients = new List<Client>();
            }

            if (allClients == null || allClients.Count == 0)
            {
                //trick to show footer when there is no data in the gridview
                allClients.Add(new Client());
                myGridview.DataSource = allClients;
                myGridview.DataBind();
                myGridview.Rows[0].Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                myGridview.DataSource = allClients;
                myGridview.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

I see this [tutorial](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2015/04/part-2-how-to-implement-basic-crud-functionality-entity-framework-aspnet-webforms.html)

> Solution

```
private void PopulateClients()
    {
        List<Client> allClients = null;
        using (MyDataBaseEntities dc = new MyDataBaseEntities())
        {
            var clients = (from a in dc.Clients
                                select new
                                {
                                    a
                                });
            if (clients != null)
            {
                allClients = new List<Client>();
                foreach (var i in clients)
                {
                    allClients.Add(i.a);
                }
            }

            if (allClients == null || allClients.Count == 0)
            {
                //trick to show footer when there is no data in the gridview
                allClients.Add(new Client());
                myGridview.DataSource = allClients;
                myGridview.DataBind();
                myGridview.Rows[0].Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                myGridview.DataSource = allClients;
                myGridview.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting no data because you don't use the data fecthed from the query (that are inside `IEnumerable<Clients> clients`).
You just check that `clients` is different from null and then you create another istance of `List<Clients>` and after all you bind allClients that it's clearly empty.

```
            var clients = (from a in dc.Clients
                                select new
                                {
                                    a
                                }).ToList();
            if (clients != null && clients.Any())
            {
                myGridview.DataSource = clients;
                myGridview.DataBind();
                myGridview.Rows[0].Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                myGridview.DataSource = clients;
                myGridview.DataBind();
            }
```

Comment: I am getting this Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery, DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList(). For ASP.NET WebForms you can bind to the result of calling ToList() on the query or use Model Binding, for more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=389592.

Comment: Corrected, now it should works. The errpr was cause by clients that by default was `IEnumerable<Clients>` and not `List<Clients>`

Comment: thnx a lot, My problem is as u write " don't use the data fecthed from the query "

Comment: just add this if (clients != null)
                {
                    allClients = new List<Client>();
                    foreach (var i in clients)
                    {
                        allClients.Add(i.a);
                    }
                }